# How can I generate exe from QT project?

Tags: qt, installation, exe

I have a project and I plan to send any human , I want to she/he can use anything only installing my exe. How can I do this?

Comment: Buy Qt Commercial license and create a statically compiled exe

Comment: I dont have commercial license :S and it is expensive for only one project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an [installer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installer#Installer), these allow you to select all needed dependencies and package them into a single archive and extract it into a designated folder.

To find these dependencies there is the [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

I personally use [nsis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) for this.

Comment: I used nsis but it creates a exe includes my files. But my app will not execute without any ide-sdk. Am I false?

Comment: you need to include some of the QT dlls you find in the sdk,

Comment: I tried it. I put qt dll in my project folder. And I generate exe by nsis. When I run the exe on other pc, I get an error that there isnot qt dll.

Comment: My problem is alive! Do you have any idea?